# Python query using groupby function on multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, grouping

I have a data frame df where df=

```
Practice    Month    DDD    MDM    BNF    Patient registered

1             1       4      67     A       1000

1             2       5      56     A       1010

2             1       6      45     B       1050

3             2       5      100    B       1100
```

I have to write python code to add a new column to my dataframe i.e. DDD_per_patient per month by each practice by grouping practice, month and BNF and by dividing patient registered with total DDD
and my dataframe is very large in size

Comment: Please post your expected output based on sample input.

Comment: @munia does this answer help?

Comment: Yes I got the output  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this help:

```
def DDD_per_patient_per_month(group):
  group["DDD_per_patient per month"] = group["Patients Registered"] / group["DDD"]
  return group

df.groupby(["Practice", "Month", "BNF"]).apply(DDD_per_patient_per_month)
```

Output:

```
    Practice    Month   DDD MDM BNF Patients Registered DDD_per_patient per month
0          1      1       4 67  A   1000                250.0
1          1      2       5 56  A   1010                202.0
2          2      1       6 45  B   1050                175.0
3          3      2       5 100 B   1100                220.0
```